# dissatisfactions of\ETC. ! Paragraph ended before \@citex was complete

Tags: pdftex

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018/W32TeX) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./1.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch level 2
Babel <3.18> and hyphenation patterns for 84 language(s) loaded.
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/elsarticle/elsarticle.cls
Document Class: elsarticle 2009/09/17, 1.2.0: Elsevier Ltd
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def)))
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/pifont.sty
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/upzd.fd)
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/upsy.fd)) (./1.spl)
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/natbib/natbib.sty))
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lineno/lineno.sty)
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-hyperref.sty
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/hobsub-generic.sty))
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty)
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/auxhook.sty)
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty)
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/hyperref.cfg)
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty))
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/rerunfilecheck.sty))
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/tabularx.sty
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/array.sty))
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/adjustbox/adjustbox.sty
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex)))
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/adjustbox/adjcalc.sty)
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/adjustbox/trimclip.sty
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/collectbox/collectbox.sty)
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/adjustbox/tc-pdftex.def))
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ifoddpage/ifoddpage.sty)
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/varwidth/varwidth.sty)) (./1.aux)
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/epstopdf-base.sty
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/grfext.sty)
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(c:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/gettitlestring.sty)) (./1.out)
 (./1.out)

Package natbib Warning: Citation `Espn2020' on page 1 undefined on input line 2
8.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `Statistica2020' on page 1 undefined on input 
line 28.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `Frontofficesports2020' on page 1 undefined on
 input line 28.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `Statista2020' on page 1 undefined on input li
ne 29.

Runaway argument?
{Guardian2020). There was same comments revealing dissatisfactions of\ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \@citex was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.42 

? 



@misc{Guardian2020,
author = {Guardian},
title = {{'This could be the end for a few clubs'. sports fans on coronavirus.Sport.The Guardian}},
url = {https://www.theguardian.com/sport/2020/mar/18/coronavirus-fans-supporters-amateur-athletes-coaches-pandemic-world},
urldate = {2020-06-03}
}


\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{lineno,hyperref}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphics}
\journal{Sport Management Review}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\modulolinenumbers[5]
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.jpg,.png}
\begin{document}
\begin{frontmatter}
\title{Thesis \tnoteref{}}
\section*{References}
 \bibliographystyle{agsm} 
\bibliography{c:/users/pars/desktop/professorDichson}
\end{frontmatter}
\end{document}
```

Would you please kindly tell me whats wrong?, I omitted unusual signs in titles in the Meneley Bib file as well. TNX

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You have `{Guardian2020)` written somewhere, rather than `{Guardian2020}`.

Comment: Thank u ,@PhelypeOleinik,